# how to change atom-live-server default browser

Tags: atom-editor

Does anyone have experience changing the default browser for atom-live-server? The documentation says to add, `{"browser" : "browser-name"}`, to `atom-live-server.json`. I did that and the default live server browser did not change from Chrome which is my default browser for macos 10.14.1. Here is the `atom-live-server.json` file, but it didn't work.

```
{
  "atom-workspace": {
    "ctrl-alt-3": "atom-live-server:start-3000",
    "ctrl-alt-4": "atom-live-server:start-4000",
    "ctrl-alt-5": "atom-live-server:start-5000",
    "ctrl-alt-8": "atom-live-server:start-8000",
    "ctrl-alt-9": "atom-live-server:start-9000",
    "ctrl-alt-l": "atom-live-server:startServer",
    "ctrl-alt-q": "atom-live-server:stopServer"
  }
  {
     "browser" : "Firefox"
  }
}
```

Does atom-live-server always use the macos default browser so you can't actually change it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is caused by a simple syntax error in your JSON file. You need to separate keys with a comma. Your file should look like the following (note the comma on line 10):

```
{
  "atom-workspace": {
    "ctrl-alt-3": "atom-live-server:start-3000",
    "ctrl-alt-4": "atom-live-server:start-4000",
    "ctrl-alt-5": "atom-live-server:start-5000",
    "ctrl-alt-8": "atom-live-server:start-8000",
    "ctrl-alt-9": "atom-live-server:start-9000",
    "ctrl-alt-l": "atom-live-server:startServer",
    "ctrl-alt-q": "atom-live-server:stopServer"
  },
  {
     "browser" : "Firefox"
  }
}
```

Comment: I added the comma but that had no effect. Still opens in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to put the following code in your .atom-live-server.json file. This file should be in your project folder.

```
{
  "browser" : "Firefox"
}
```

It works on my windows 7 system. The first few lines seem to make things worse. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've solved somehow, but I wrote this answer because I got in same situation.
(I work on Mac OS Mojave)

I did the same way Bill Zhao said.

Create a json file **.atom-live-server.json** in project file, and put

```
{
  "browser":"Firefox(or firefox)"
}
```

It's working for me. July 6 2019

Answer (score 0):

Only change your predetermined browser in your operating system.